# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, client-object-model, console-application

I try to access SharePoint list from  a console app in .NET. My environment doesn't have SharePoint installed one and I write code in VS 2013. I want to access SharePoint 2013 list data. When I run my app I get exception saying:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

What's wrong in my code?

```
string siteUrl = "http://domain:10000/";

ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Test");

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID'/>" +
"<Value Type='Number'>10</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.Load(collListItem);

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0} \nTitle: {1}", oListItem.Id, oListItem["Title"]);
}
```

Comment: I think this could be authentication issue. Your code works in my case (the difference being it is tested on SP2010 & VS2010). Have a look at [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22759278/1047998). Yes I know it's on SP Online but it may lead you somewhere.

Comment: Did you look into the exception details, ULS logs or run a Fiddler trace of the failing session? Those might shed some light on the nature of the problem.

Comment: @Naveen You are correct. It works in SP 2010 and VS 2010. But not in VS 2013 & SP 2013. Hope in SP 2013 there may be a new access barrier in client context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently did something similar.
I had to add references to the following:-

Microsoft.SharePoint

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime

Once had added all three of these it seemed to work fine

Hope this helps!

Comment: The first reference isn't relevant for SharePoint Online as it contains the Server Object Model that's unavailable to SPO developers.

Comment: Correction: SharePoint Online or off-box remote APIs such as CSOM and JSOM in general.